# npm got.post() returns something I don't understand

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get something from a third party server, and I'm using got to make the https, but now it's returning something I can't understand.

```
let res = got.post('https://c.jushuitan.com/api/open/query.aspx?ts=1632820982&partnerid=ywv5jGT8ge6Pvlq3FZSPol345asd&method=mall.item.query&token=181ee8952a88f5a57db52587472c3798&sign=e101d5a0662dc9723415a941d4f2d606', {
        json: {
            "modified_begin": "2021-09-06 00:00:00",
            "modified_end": "2021-09-07 00:00:00",
            "page_index": index,
            "page_size": size,
            "sku_ids": null
        }
    })
    console.log('2')
    console.log(res)
```

and the return info is like this:
[image]

What is this? Am I using got wrong?

Comment: Did you try reading [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got), which explain how to use the response in various scenarios?

Comment: You're not using it "wrong", you are simply looking at the `Response` object this returned. You need to further work with that now, to get what data you are interested in out of it. https://www.npmjs.com/package/got#response

Answer (score 2):

The `.post()` returns a promise. You need to `await` it or handle with `.then`

From [got npm's page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got):

```js
const {body} = await got.post('YOUR_ENDPOINT', {
        json: {
            hello: 'world'
        },
        responseType: 'json'
    });

console.log(body.data);
```

Or you may try:

```js
got.post('YOUR_ENDPOINT', {
        json: {
            hello: 'world'
        },
        responseType: 'json'
    }).then(result => doSomething(result))
```